# How to encode the HTML input in ckeditor in angular

Tags: angular, ckeditor4.x

I am using ng2-ckeditor in my angular project i need to encode the < and > as &lt ,&gt ,so how to encode the input HTML

```
.html                                                                                                       
<ckeditor> </ckeditor>
<button type="button" (click) ="submit()">Click Me!</button>
```

.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var CKEDITOR: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-html-editor',
  templateUrl: './html-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./html-editor.component.css']
})


export class HtmlEditorComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit() {


  }

  submit() {
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
    var data = editor.getData();
    console.log(data)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert whatever character you want. Below is code that will take str as input and return converted string.

```
function convertHTML(str) {
    // &colon;&rpar;
    var Regcheck = /\W\s/gi;
    var htmlListObj = {'&':"&amp;",
                      "<":"&lt;",
                      ">":"&gt;",
                      '"':"&quot;",
                      "'":"&apos;"};
    var a = str.split("");
    var b =[];

    for (var i in a) {
         if (htmlListObj.hasOwnProperty(a[i])) {
             b.push( htmlListObj[a[i]]);
         }else{
             b.push(a[i]);
         } 
    }
    var c = b.join("");
   return c;
}
```

Comment: whether ckeditor is having any functionality to encode the input html ,bcoz i have searched something like  htmlEncodeOutput = true but its not working for me

Comment: This is solution which you can use. htmlEncodeOutput having some issues, you can check on following link : https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/CKEditor-3.x/HTML-encode

Comment: link you referred also they are suggesting to use config.htmlEncodeOutput = true; but that is not working for .

Comment: can you  plz tell me how to decode the input back to original form

Comment: Just reverse function.

Comment: whether need to reverse the object?

Comment: yes... now you need to do reverse what you have replaced. It will back on normal string.